# Is it possible for a Windows 7 Gadget to bring itself to the top?

Tags: windows-7, alert, windows-desktop-gadgets

I am developing a monitor gadget that monitors production exceptions (by making JSONP Ajax requests).

Most of the time the information is not of interest and I wish for it to be behind other windows.

However, when an exception occurs, I would like for the gadget bring itself to the top of other windows to let me know of the problem.

Is this possible, does anyone know? I have a feeling not... is there another way that people can suggest? Or is it that windows gadgets are not really suitable for this sort of thing.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use the System Toast to notify in case of exception.

Comment: I've never heard of System Toast, and, it seems, neither had google. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Apologies for using a Non Generic Term. I was suggesting the System Tray Notification Bubbles as @Bueller has pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

However, I have managed to achieve the effect I wanted. Namely I set the gadget to be "always on top" and then have a minimized state that shrinks the gadget down to the smallest it can be and sets the background to an icon (surrounded by transparency). This give me an unobtrusive icon that I can dock into the top right of the screen.

Then, when an event occurs that I want to display, I have a Maximize() method in JS that restores the width/height of the gadget and shows some content (I actually use jQuery's animate method to do this which gives a nice "expansion", similar to the dock/undock transition).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it this is available for gadgets but on Windows machines you can use the Notification area.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx

Comment: Erm... no, don't think it is available.